# Permissions of my application in BB10 location settings is always in disabled mode

Tags: android, blackberry-10

I have created a sample android application using location manager and ported that to blackberry z10.When i install and access location services in bb10 device settings, my application permission is always in disabled mode (toggle can't able to on/off) even when i change device location service to on/off.
;

Comment: Exactly how "compatible" is BB10 WRT location services? Have you checked?

Answer (score 2):

1. Open Settings - pull down from the top bezel
2. Select Security and Privacy
3. Select App Permissions
4. Open up the app and you can toggle on and off the features you don't want the app to have access to.

Answer (score 0):

Your Anddroid application must have the permission set in Manfest.permission, probably ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, though I am not an Android expert, so may be mistaken.

Once the application is configured with the permissions it needs to operate, the BlackBerry 10 device will query for authorization of the permissions on installation. The version of Android emulated on BlackBerry 10 does not allow modification of application permissions post-installation.

As a side note, on BlackBerry 10, no application can be granted a permission which is not requested in the manifest.